# Video from matrix matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix [3][120] in a text file and I want to generate a video from it. How do I go about that?

So far I have done the following: I have read the data from the text file and stored it in a variable. From here I want to generate the video represented by the matrix. Or is there a way to split the matrix into frames because I want to split the video into frames then combine the frames again to get the video back. Then I would compare the original video with the current one

```
clear all
clc
filename='filename.txt';
delimiterIn=' ';
K=importdata(filename,delimiterIn);
```

from here how do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide enough info about the movie you want to make. The procedure to make a movie is highlighted on this [page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movie2avi.html). The key is to call getframe inside the loop to generate movies. I am modifying matlab's example to your work:

```
    clear all
    clc
    filename='filename.txt';
    delimiterIn=' ';
    K=importdata(filename,delimiterIn);
    % K =load(filename) may also work
    nFrames = 20;

    % Preallocate movie structure.
    mov(1:nFrames) = struct('cdata', [],...
                    'colormap', []);

    % Create movie.
    plot(K(:,1), K(:,2));  % assumes you are plotting the first two colums 
    axis tight manual
    set(gca,'nextplot','replacechildren');
    for k = 1:nFrames 
       plot(K(:,1), K(:,2));  % assumes you are plotting the first two columns
                              % the data must somehow change inside this loop
       mov(k) = getframe(gcf);
    end

    % Create AVI file.
    movie2avi(mov, 'mydata.avi', 'compression', 'None');
```

Another interface is the videowriter interface which is present in the more recent versions of matlab.
It is explained [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter-class.html). and is recommended than the above proceedure. Please follow the suggestions there. The page is simple to follow.

```
    clear all
    clc
    filename='filename.txt';
    delimiterIn=' ';
    K=importdata(filename,delimiterIn);
    % K =load(filename) may also work


    %Prepare the new file.

    writerObj = VideoWriter('movie.avi');
    open(writerObj);
    % Create movie.
    plot(K(:,1), K(:,2));  % assumes you are plotting the first two colums 
    axis tight manual

    set(gca,'nextplot','replacechildren');
    set(gcf,'Renderer','zbuffer'); % optional I think

    for k = 1:nFrames 
       plot(K(:,1), K(:,2));  % assumes you are plotting the first two columns
                              % the data must somehow change inside this loop
       frame = getframe(gcf);
       writeVideo(writerObj,frame);
    end 
   close(writerObj);
```

Comment: have tried the above methods. however when I play the .avi file created its just a graph. not a video. any help

Comment: As I have commented, the matrix K columns 1 and 2 must change from frame to frame because to make a movie you need data changing at every frame. Does your data change from frame to frame?

Comment: I am a newbie in video processing in matlab I guess thats why I am encountering a bunch of problems. would you mind sending me your email so that i can send the file itself. otherwise I may not be able to explain fully